# Is it possible to count all the items that satisfy predicate and the ones that don't in one iteration over the table?

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a query:

```cs
var x = from c in _context
        [...]
        group subResult by subResult.Id into g
        select new 
        { 
            g.Key,
            Count1 = g.Where(predicate).Count(), 
            Count2 = g.Where(!predicate).Count()
        }
```

Is it possible to simplify query if predicates used for `Count1` and `Count2` if `g.Count()==Count1 + Count2` so counting isn't done twice and still on server-side?

---

EDIT: This is what I get

[image]

Comment: Do you have performance issues? Answer will change query cardinally.

Comment: Couldn't you modify the groupBy to contain this like `.GroupBy(c => new { c.subResult, isOrderedToday = c.OrderDate.Day == today  } `?

Comment: What makes you think counting is done twice?. There are three terms in `Count=Count1+Count2`, you always need to know two of them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the EF tag. If this is going to the DB then you don't know how many counts are being done. EF and the DB both can optimize the query. You need to profile it on the DB. If this where in memory objects then you need to determine the types involved to see the expense of the operation. `g.Where(predicate).Count()` doesn't always need to iterate through `g`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to solve here? Do you have a performance issue? As already mentioned, some SQL will be generated by EF, and that SQL will almost definitely only read through the table once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how using `Aggregate`:

```
var x =
    from c in _context
    [...]
    group subResult by subResult.Id into g
    let count = g.Aggregate((t: 0, f : 0), (a, x) => predicate(x) ? (a.t + 1, a.f) : (a.t, a.f + 1))
    select new
    {
        g.Key,
        Count1 = count.t,
        Count2 = count.f
    };
```

You do actually want to know what type `g` is as if it is a `IPartition<T>` then `Count` is `O(1)` and then `Aggregate` performs more poorly.

Comment: Could you have a look at my edit? I tried to use that approach.

Comment: Ok, I see it's a game over because: "Aggregate is not supported by linq-to-entities (regardless of what function you pass in). Remember that SQL is set-based, so custom aggregations are often very difficult to translate to SQL." and I need server side execution.